# Feature Policy Safari - Iframes - Youtube - ReactJS

Tags: iframe, youtube, fullscreen

I am working on my website and noticed an error that I cant figure out that deals with Feature Policy.

In Google Chrome, I do not receive the error but in Safari I do. 
"Feature policy 'Fullscreen' check failed for iframe with origin 'https://www.youtube.com' and allow attribute ''."

I went and added "allow="autoplay; fullscreen"" to all of my youtube iframes but this has not solved the issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have also used allowFullScreen and allowFullScreen='allowFullScreen'

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable "Develop menu" in [Safari settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7D40.png)
2. From the menu bar open "Develop" > "Experimental Features" > "Reset All to Defaults" ([scroll to the bottom to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQXeK.jpg))
3. Quit Safari (command + Q) and open it again and check if you error is fixed.

You may receive a prompt related to fullscreen permission, grant it.